# Is the react-native-video library compatible with an expo project?

Tags: react-native, video, expo, react-native-video

I want to implement this library into my expo project, however I'm having difficulties even getting an example up. Is this library compatible?

npm package link: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-video

Answer (score 4):

You can use [Custom Development Client](https://blog.expo.dev/introducing-custom-development-clients-5a2c79a9ddf8) to use this library in an `Expo Managed Project`.

If you don't want to change anything in your project and use it as it is, you can try [Expo AV](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/video/). This provides a Video Component which you can use.

Comment: I can verify that you can use  react-native-video with eas build without any config plugin.